# How Can I Retrieve The SessionStatistics for a Specific Workflow Run Id via the Informatica Webservice?

Tags: web-services, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a workflow that contains several tasks.  When the workflow runs and completes, I want to retrieve the session statistics (typically, via `getSessionStatistics` web service call).  However, there may be many copies of the workflow running, each with their own set of tasks.  I have the workflow run id for the workflow I want.  How can I get the statistics for that specific run, instead of the current or latest run?

Comment: Tip : Write a shell(unix) script to store each session statistics/logs to a log file, say `(wf_123.out)` and then use/call this file where you need.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are asking how to store the session statistics i.e session name, source_success_count,target_success_count,failure_count,start and end time of that particular session right?

if it is so, create an assignment task for all session and create workflow variables. Assign session variables for these workflow flow variables. so that u can store all details in a seperate table and can be filtered out based on our job start and end time.

If your question is not exactly this sorry for the wrong one

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to Informatica Repository Metadata DataBase you can query it for all kind of statistics, including detailed session stats. Please find example queries here (11.1 seems suitable):

http://www.etltechblog.com/p/informatica.html

You may need to tinker with the query a little, because depending on the repository version the table names differ a little, but the schema stays the same.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10857347)

Comment: Right, thanks for the feedback, I'll improve that in my future posts.